# What is the purpose of ValidationResult.Success field?

Tags: entity-framework, validation

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult.success.aspx):

> public static readonly ValidationResult ValidationResult.Success
>
> Represents the success of the validation (true if validation was
>   successful; otherwise, false).

The text in above excerpt doesn't make sense to me, since `Success` field doesn't return a value of type `bool`, and the value it does return ( ie `ValidationResult` instance ) doesn't contain any boolean property or field which we could set to a value indicating a success or failure of a validation?!

Any ideas what is the purpose of this field?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`ValidationResult.Success` is always constant `null`. Its purpose is **documentation**.

In order to succeed validation you could either write:

```
return null;
```

or

```
return ValidationResult.Success;
```

In the first case I ask myself "**What does this mean? What does null mean? Is this success, or fail, or something else?**". In the latter case the code is **inherently documented** without the need for informal text docs.

Comment: In case you'll still be reading this - I forgot to ask why does quote indicate ( "...; otherwise, false" ) that Success field could also indicate unsuccessful validation

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that part of the question. The docs are just wrong ;-) I guess the MVC team originally had the validator return a boolean. That is not enough, though, so they changed it. This is another case for docs as code as opposed to docs as text!

Comment: How do you check if `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` doesn't have errors?

Comment: @Shimmy `if (model.Validate().Any()) { displayErrors(...) }`